# Show Blog Posts With Their Slug Name Not Its Title

Tags: wordpress, posts

Respected sir,

I want to show the blog posts but instead the title i want to show the slug without dash sign like in wp query code

not hello-word i want this one hello word

Comment: Respected sir,
Please tell me something about this.

Comment: 30 days spend but not any solution Any luck ?